# How to pass ASP.NET Identity UserId to stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-identity

I need to pass the ASP.NET Identity UserId as a parameter to a stored procedure, but I'm not sure how to get the ID from a logged in user?

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserProfile]
@UserId nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Avatar, City, [State]
    FROM UserProfiles
    WHERE UserId = @UserId
END
```

**Stored Procedure call from Repository:**

```
public List<UserModels.UserProfile> GetUserProfile()
{
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SQLSettings.GetConnectionString()))
{
    return connection.Query<UserModels.UserProfile>("GetUserProfile", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of the `UserId`, are you okay to use the `UserName` instead? If you are using ASP.NET MVC, you can get the UserName from within your controller action by using `User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: Thanks @OldProgrammer! I was able to get the ID using response by @peter_the_oak in the link you provided.